# Problems using a C# singleton in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, dll, singleton

I'm having some trouble getting my singleton class to cooperate when I try to load it into PowerShell. Specifically, I am getting the following error when I try to access the instance:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\*Omitted*\Documents\visual studio
2012\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\test.ps1:5 char:1
+ $test = [ClassLibrary1.Class1]::Instance.Foo()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

When I run this sample script:

```
$currentScriptDirectory = Get-Location
[System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($currentScriptDirectory.Path)
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("ClassLibrary1.dll") | fl
[ClassLibrary1.Class1] | Get-Member -Static
$test = [ClassLibrary1.Class1]::Instance.Foo()
```

On this simple class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private static Class1 instance = null;

        private Class1()
        {

        }

        public static Class1 Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (null == instance)
                {
                    instance = new Class1();
                }

                return instance;
            }
        }

        public string Foo()
        {
            return "HI THERE";
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to get rid of this error without changing the class from a singleton? I've inherited the class I'm working with and can't change its architecture.

Comment: Your class is not a singleton, your Instance property should be static, and when you do make it static, you will still lack thread-safety. Read: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx for information on different ways to implement a singleton in C#.

Comment: As I said in my comment to alex, the actual class has the correct static markers, as does the sample code after the edit. And since I don't have ownership of the class, I can't modify it.

Comment: It is still not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you got static and instance confused. Static means it's class-level, e.g. the instance. The `Foo` method should be instance, as that's seemingly what you want. Here's the fixed code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private static Class1 instance = null;
        private Class1()
        {
        }
        public static Class1 Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (null == instance)
                {
                    instance = new Class1();
                }

                return instance;
            }
        }
        public string Foo()
        {
            return "HI THERE";
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is not a bulletproof singleton pattern. Jon Skeet has made some good ones, here.

Here's a proper implementation of it:

```
public sealed class Class1
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Class1> lazy =
        new Lazy<Class1>(() => new Class1());
    public static Class1 Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
    private Class1()
    {
    }
    public string Foo()
    {
        return "HI THERE";
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1059895 Working on that, doing some powershell testing.

Comment: @user1059895 Problem is at your end, did some extra testing and it works.